# What files/directories are needed to recreate a Xilinx PlanAhead project?

Tags: xilinx, planahead

I wish to make sure the input files are checked into source control so I (or others) can build, recreate, branch/modify a design. However with PlanAhead, the same suffixes are used for both input and output files.

Yes, I did ask Xilinx in a WebCase, but didn't get a good answer. I don't wish an answer on the lines of "all of these directories" where that includes many output files. Some of the suffixes are [in this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/12891/list-of-xilinx-file-suffixes) but that answer isn't sufficient since xml files are used for both inputs and outputs.

Knowing what files/directories aren't needed would also be helpful. Then I could ask Xilinx about those files/directories that aren't known.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The .ppr file is the PlanAhead project file.
2. Assuming the project is named `project`, it references these files which appear to be needed

> ```
> ./project.data/constrs_1/fileset.xml
> ./project.data/sources_1/fileset.xml
> ./project.data/runs/runs.xml
> ./project.data/runs/impl_1.psg
> ```

runs.xml seems to also contain output/status information so changes onrecompile.

impl_1.psg contains bitgen options.

1. Assuming ChipScope

> ```
> ./project.sources_1/chipscope.xml
> ./project.data/sources_1/cs/u_icon*/u_icon.ngc
> ./project.data/sources_1/cs/cs_il*/cs_ila*.ngc
> ```

Files you don't need:

`wt/` (webtalk)

Files that I don't know if needed or not

```
./project.data/runs/synth_1/constrs_in.xml
./project.data/runs/synth_1/sources.xml
```